# Getting gdbserver + gdb in VSCode to load symbols as fast as gdb alone

Tags: gdb, vscode-debugger, debug-symbols, gdbserver

When debugging my binary with gdb and `set auto-solib-add on` and `set index-cache enabled on`, the loading of symbols at the start takes 2-3 seconds.

When however starting gdbserver on the host, a VSCode proxy on the same host and in that VSCode, creating a launch.json to configure gdb to connect to gdbserver, the loading symbols part takes 40 seconds.

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:1234",
            "useExtendedRemote: true,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/install/program",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "text": "source {workspaceFolder}/.gdbinit-gdbserver",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's .gdbinit-gdbserver:

```
maint set worker-threads unlimited
set auto-solib-add on
set index-cache enabled on
```

I know the gdbinit file is correctly read because when it's sourced I can see the cache filling up at `~/.cache/gdb`

I'd like to know if there's a way to speed this up.

I tried to do the following workaround:  get the program to start without loading debug symbols and pause at the first line, then execute `sharedlibrary theOnlyLibraryImInterestedIn.so`. That's much faster but I can only do it manually, by entering `-exec sharedlibrary theOnlyLibraryImInterestedIn.so` in the VSCode debug terminal. I couldn't find a way to automate it, the issue being I can't find a way to pass commands to VSCode that should be executed after the `stopAtEntry` pause kicks in.

Another way would be to stop gdb from looking for libraries in the default search location, and only search in the `solib-search-path`, so I could limit the loading to one specific library I'm interested in. But I couldn't find a way to prevent gdb from searching in default paths.